# How to properly run Python using Docker/Kubenertes?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have a simple python code, but I can't get it running on Docker nor Kubernetes.

I'm building, tagging and pushing my image and than running

```
docker build -t test . --no-cache
docker tag test tcnl/test:0.2
docker push tcnl/test
docker run tcnl/test:0.2
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server example
print("Listening...")
import socket
print("Listening...")
import sys
print("Listening...")

s = socket.socket()
print("Listening...")
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8765
s.bind((host, port))
print("Listening...")
s.listen(5)
print("B4 while")
try:

    c, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        print("INSIDE TRUE")
        print('Got connection from', addr)
        c.send(("Connection accepted!").encode('utf-8'))
        print(str(c.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')))
except:
    print("Oops!",sys.exc_info(),"occured.")
    input()
s.close()
```

It's meant to be just a websocket server, waiting for a connection an then just send messages. But not even that is working...
Now my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
MAINTAINER tcnl

# Creating Application Source Code Directory
RUN mkdir -p /test/src

# Setting Home Directory for containers
WORKDIR /test/src

# Installing python dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /test/src/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copying src code to Container
COPY ./test-server.py /test/src/test.py

# Application Environment variables
ENV APP_ENV development

# Exposing Ports
EXPOSE 8765

# Setting Persistent data
VOLUME ["/test-data"]

# Running Python Application
CMD python /test/src/test.py
```

When I run on docker the program doesn't even print. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `docker run -it tcnl/test:0.2` it would bind docker stdout to your terminal and you will see output:

## Docker

```
# docker run -it tcnl/test:0.2
Listening...
Listening...
Listening...
Listening...
Listening...
B4 while
```

## Kubernetes

`kubectl run -it test-server --restart=Never --image=tcnl/test:0.2`

To get output:
`kubectl logs test-server`

```
Listening...
Listening...
Listening...
Listening...
Starting Flask...
Listening...
B4 while
```

Comment: When I run: cat .\equipment.yaml | linkerd inject - | kubectl apply -f -  , then
kubectl logs -f equipment-service -c equipment-container --namespace=linkerd-test
To link a deployment file to Linkerd, then try to get the logs from the POD, it's blank. Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: I am not familiar with linkerd but show output from `kubectl get all`

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Linkerd is not causing the problem, I have run other images with linkerd before and I was able to get the logs, but with this Python script, I cant.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the commands you are running and Kubernetes manifests so we have some information to debug against. We can only speculate without more information.

Comment: This is my command `kubectl run -it test-server --restart=Never --image=tcnl/test:0.2` that is running kubernetes manifest, if you need yaml for it just run `kubectl run -it test-server --restart=Never --image=tcnl/test:0.2 --dry-run -o yaml`